# python, calculate a hockey salary with an if else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

**About the program I am creating:** 
This is a calculate salary homework problem I didnt do to well on. The problem was to ask the user for five inputs. Base Salary, Goals, Asst, player scored, scored against player. Use the input to calculate how much the got for goals+asst. If total was under 75 points, $5000 a point. If total was above 75 points, $10,000 for each point above 75 and the rest $5000. Use the input to calculate the plus minus score. Subtract goals made by player from goals made against player. If total was positive $25000 a point. Then display total money earned.

**Where I am:**
I have the input down, and the points down, I feel like i have the plus minus score code right but it's not calculating it into the end result. I also am a bit stumped on how to add everything together and print total.

---

```
 salary = int(input('Enter base salary for player: '))
    goals = int(input('Enter goals scored by player: '))
    asst = int(input('Enter assists credited to the player: '))
    scored = int(input('Enter goals we scored when player was on the ice: '))
    against = int(input('Enter goals against player, when player was on the ice: '))

    scoring_point = 0 
    plus_minus = 0

    if scoring_point > 75: 
        scoring_point = goals + asst
        point_bonus_greater = (scoring_point - 75) * 10000
        point_2 = point_bonus_greater + 375000
        print ('total for points is: $', point_2)
    elif scoring_point < 75:
        scoring_point = goals + asst
        scoring_point2 = scoring_point * 5000
        print('total for points is: $', scoring_point2)
    elif plus_minus > 0:
        plus_minus2 = plus_minus * 25000
        print ('total plus/minus: $', plus_minus2)
    else:
        print('i suck')
```

Comment: You set 'scoring_point' and 'plus_minus' to 0 regardless of input. There is no chance for any if statement other than `elif scoring_point < 75:` to trigger.